# Does anyone know a good .Net VoIP library?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, clickonce, voip

I have been searching for ages now for a good .Net based VoIP library.
After having tried conaito and SIP.Net, I have still haven't found anything that truly fits my needs.

Basically all of these are constructed using ActiveX. Unfortunately ActiveX and WPF don't play well together. And ClickOnce Deployment doesn't register Interop COM components.

I need to find a good and pure .Net managed code implementation.

Comment: So to cap this one off, there was no managed code implementation that we could find that would work for this. So we ended up paying for the development of one from Abto llc. It was a really good lib (that I am sure they are now selling on) that did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this off, a few years ago we got ABTO llc to build us a custom version of their SIP client.

It was a managed code implementation that we purchased from them.

It worked very well, but the project was canned later on.

Thanks for all the info and answers.

Answer (score 1):

What about these...

- [Asterisk Arena - AmiConnector](http://www.asteriskarena.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=57) (might not be good because of the ActiveX stuff)
- Guide from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Video_Voice_Conferencing.aspx)
- List of [Free Libraries](http://www.roseindia.net/voip/free-voip-software-development-library.shtml)

Hope these are useful, apologies if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked and answered in the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).
The [Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7500) and the [detailed answer covering different options and summary](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9869).

**A Sneak peek from original question/answer:**

***Promising:***

- [Ozeki](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/)
- [Abto](http://www.voipsipsdk.com/)
- [PCBest SIP SDK](http://www.pcbest.net/sip_sdk.php)
- [LanScape VoIP Media Engine](http://www.lanscapecorp.com/ProductPages/LanScapeVoipMediaEngine.asp)
- [Conaito SIP Client SDK](http://www.conaito.com/products/voip-sip-client-sdk)
- [VaxVoIP SIP Phone SDK](http://vaxvoip.com/phonesdk.html)
- [Sipek SDK](https://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/sipeksdk)
- [Counterpath Softphone Development Kit](http://www.counterpath.com/sdk.html)
- [IntTalk VoIP SDK](http://www.minerva-soft.com/#!inttalk-voip-sdk/c3jb)

***Not so promising:***

- [pjsip wrapper](https://sites.google.com/site/sipekvoip/Home/documentation/pjsipwrapper)
- [VoiceElements VE Platform](http://www.voiceelements.com/products/veplatform.aspx) (targeted as cloud service or in house telephony service, not so much what we need)
- [PortSIP SDK](http://www.portsip.com/voipsdk.html) (DLL import necessary)

***Not at all:***

- [Independentsoft](http://www.independentsoft.com/sip/index.html) (no RTP)
- [Konnetic](http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx) (no RTP)

Credits to @BatteryBackupUnit

Answer (score 0):

[pjsip.net](http://sites.google.com/site/sipekphone/pjsipwrapper) which is an C# wrapper on the C [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) library.

[sipsorcery](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/) fully C# SIP library, incomplete as far as RTP and media functions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/)

Comment: promising but finally sucks. I spent days trying to make it work. different behavior without changing code....